# Construção de indíces SQL + Chave primária composta

Tags: sql, sql-server, índices

Poderiam me ajudar na criação de um índice?

A minha tabela possui como chave primária a combinação de 3 colunas (a decisão foi tomada devido a quantidade de linhas), porém a consulta aos dados da tabela está problemática e muito demorada quando consultamos somente por 1 das colunas, por exemplo.

Acredito que a criação de um índice iria ajudar na performance e tempo de retorno das informações.

Estrutura da tabela
Tamanho da tabela: 986.270.109 MB
Quantidade de Linhas: 23.142.422.498

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TB_ARQUIVO_CONTEUDOS](
    [ID_ARQUIVO] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [ID_COLUNA] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [NUM_LINHA] [int] NOT NULL,
    [VAL_COLUNA] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [DAT_ULT_ATUALIZACAO] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [CK_TB_ARQUIVO_CONTEUDOS] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID_ARQUIVO] ASC,
    [ID_COLUNA] ASC,
    [NUM_LINHA] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: A pk é algo que identifique de forma única o registro. Porque a decisão da pk veio da quantidade de linhas ?? Como é feita a consulta ? Qual(ais) a(s) princinpal(ais) consulta(s)? Foi feita a "explain plan" das sqls ?

Answer (score -2):

Você pode criar VIEWS que são nada menos do que consultas SQL que realizam a junção de uma ou mais tabelas e salvam estes resultados em uma espécie de tabela virtual, onde poderá ser acessada normalmente utilizando um SELECT.

**Mas afinal, qual a vantagem em utilizar este recurso?**

Para tabelas com muitas linhas, as VIEWS são necessárias para economizar tempo retornando apenas colunas necessárias e também registros que precisam.

Há fontes que descrevem o tempo de retorno de uma query SQL utilizando tabela comum e uma VIEW como sendo iguais, mudando pouca coisa da duração da consulta.

**Mas e se isso não resolver o meu problema?**

Daí quando temos tabelas com uma grande quantidade de dados e ainda mais com bilhões de registros, terão servidores locais e até mesmo remotos que não darão conta desta imensa quantidade de dados e ainda mais com várias chaves primárias. A única alternativa que resta é a paginação.

**Onde utilizamos a paginação?**

Podemos utilizá-la em qualquer lugar, aliás em todas as tabelas de um banco de dados devemos colocar paginação, para garantir que não haja sobrecarga de registros ou demora na realização de uma consulta envolvendo uma ou mais tabelas.

A única exceção para este caso será de quando tivermos uma tabela de N:N (muitos para muitos) onde em sua maioria elas armazenam somente a chave primária das tabelas que se relacionam com elas, daí não será necessário uma paginação específica para a entidade que recebe este tipo de relacionamento.

**Portanto posso criar uma VIEW com todos os dados que preciso filtrando algumas condições para não trazer todas as linhas de uma vez?**

Sim, isso é permitido, mas se fizer isso e mesmo assim a consulta trazer milhões de linhas, o que será provavelmente com mais chances de acontecer, é recomendado utilizar a paginação.

No exemplo abaixo está um exemplo de paginação utilizando SELECT a partir de uma tabela comum, mas pode também criar uma VIEW e fazer a paginação normalmente:

```sql
SELECT e.* FROM employee e ORDER BY e.first_name ASC LIMIT 3, 5; -- Exemplo em MySQL
```

[image: teste]

[Conceitos e criação de views no SQL Server](https://www.devmedia.com.br/conceitos-e-criacao-de-views-no-sql-server/22390)

[MYSQL – Trabalhando com Views](https://www.devmedia.com.br/mysql-trabalhando-com-views/8724)

[Equivalente a LIMIT e OFFSET para SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135418/equivalent-of-limit-and-offset-for-sql-server)

Comment: Criar uma VIEW não me ajudaria, pois o problema de indexação da tabela não seria resolvido